# Need help modifying this regex: ^\d+\.[ \t]+(.+)[ \t]+by[ \t]+(.+)$

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex:

```
^\d+\.[ \t]+(.+)[ \t]+by[ \t]+(.+)$
```

on this string:

```
1. Gulliver's Travels by Jonathan Swift
```

and performing this replacement:

```
\2 \1
```

to get this result:

```
Jonathan Swift Gulliver's Travels
```

However, I found another use case in my data where the author is not separated with `by` but by a colon and the order is reversed. Instead, it's

```
<number><period><space><author>:<space><title>
```

like this:

```
1. Jonathan Swift: Gulliver's Travels
```

How can I modify the original regex to get the same output as before?

Comment: I suppose it's a books' titles parser ? Then I'd be very careful with regex, because you can find such titles as 'Guided by Voices: A Brief History: Twenty-One Years of Hunting Accidents in the Forests of Rock and Roll by James Greer'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the following regex (I suppose there are no spaces before the colon, according to your example):

`^\d+\.[ \t]+(.+)([ \t]+by|:)[ \t]+(.+)$`

That way, if you capture a "by" in `\2` you can do `\3 \1`, else you can do `\1 \3`.

**Edit:**

Here's a simple Perl program demonstrating the above:

```
$input = <STDIN>;
chomp($input);

if($input =~ m/^\d+\.[ \t]+(.+)([ \t]+by|:)[ \t]+(.+)$/) {
    if($2 eq ":") {
    print "$1 $3\n";
    }
    else {
    print "$3 $1\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like: `^\d+\.\s(.+):\s(.+)\s*$`

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, would replace `by` in your regex with a non-capturing `(?:by|\x3A)` Also, not *too* familiar with replaced captured, but can you applied named groups to it (or otherwise explicitly make one capture \1 and the other \2)?